# Grounding in 250v & 125v

Tags: grounding

My comment is more of a question regarding the mechanics of a problem I have. It is not theory or math. I have that down pretty good.
Here is the problem:

1. let's start at the power source. We have the 3 legs of the the 250 volt center tapped AC power transformer; 2 hots & a neutral, the return leg.  The attachment) is on the meter side of my power base running in parallel to the "power in" to my house.
2. I'm building a portable second leg on my power in. I will use it for my portable wielder & other power tools & needs.
3. It will start with a 3 wire 50A extension to a NEMA 6-50R receptical box, a 2 port 3 wire grounded device.
4. Next is a 3 wire, 50 foot, 50A, grounded extension. It is terminated on both ends with grounded NEMA ends, a 50A, 6-50R receptical on one end & a NEMA 50A, 6-50P plug on the other.
5. I have the 2, 50A hots & neutral wires up & into a grounded NEMA 3 wire, 6-50R receptical outlet.
6. I am constructing an adapter that will have 2, 125VAC, 25A, NEMA 5-15R recepticals on its output. On it's input it will have a large 50A,250VAC, NEMA 6-50P, 2 pole, 3 wire, grounded plug.
7. This adapter will be incerted into the NEMA 6-50R receptical on the end of the 50 foot, 50A, 3 wire extension.
8. Here is the problem. The adapter has 2, NEMA 25A, 125VAC, 5-15R Recepticals & they have 1 hot & 1 neutral & something extra, a "ground" wire.
   That is where the mechanics of the issue is. HOW DO I TERMINATE these two grounds inside the NEMA 6-50P plug on the end  of the adapter so that they perform their function effectively?
9. If someone knows please provide me with a good complete explanation. (Remember the ground is not to be attached to system neutral). If you don't know please don't try guessing. This is important.
   Thank you for your time & consideration. I look forward to your answer soon. Have a good day all, bye for now, Ben.

Comment: You missed a major chunk of theory, actually.

Comment: Actually you are stuck at step#1 cordage is not allowed as a tap conductor. 
Step 6 again the maximum size ocpd,
Since you want this outside not only will the 20 amp circuit require GFCI but now 240v circuits will require GFCI also. 
You can use the tap rule and put a panel outside. With the appropriate receptacles that are GFCI protected. From there you can make your extension cords , your grounding conductor has to come from the same source since tapping at the transformer you have to run 4 wires from this point.  VTC , needs focus and maybe some code review.

Comment: If it is so important, go to find a consultant and pay for the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You CANNOT do step 6 and beyond without running a **4-wire** connection to that point. Hot, Hot, **Neutral and** Ground. **NEMA 14, not** NEMA 6

If you run 3-wire hot hot ground as proposed, no 120V at the far end of it, unless you put in a transformer that makes it a separate source. Which costs a lot more than a neutral wire and the proper plugs/receptacles.

If you want NEMA5-15 receptacles at the end, and you use NEMA14 to get there, you also need a subpanel (with neutral isolated from ground) to house the breakers to properly protect the NEMA5-15s, since they cannot be directly connected to a 50A supply.

Not surprisingly, you can purchase a power distribution box pre-made that already has such components.

Answer (score 3):

As you point out, NEMA 6-50 has two hots and a ground -- no neutral. NEMA 5-15 has one hot, a ground, *and a neutral*. The simple answer is that you can't easily convert NEMA 6 to NEMA 5 and comply with NEC. It's not impossible to do, just impractical. For example one could include a transformer in the adapter. One of the poles of the transformer provides neutral, another provides the 120 V hot, and ground runs right around the transformer (and, if I'm not mistaken, the transformer-derived neutral should be bonded to that ground).

The other problem to be dealt with is current limiting: presumably the 6-50 is connected to a circuit breakered for 50 amps. We can't be feeding a 15 amp receptacle directly from that.

The neutral problem is most easily fixed by using a 4-wire connection. Don't use NEMA 6-50; use NEMA 14-50 instead.

The current problem is more tricky. I'm not sure there exist UL-*listed* devices (breakers or fuses) for this. UL-*recognized* components exist; these are intended to be included in an overall appliance or device which as a whole would be UL-listed. It would be untruthful if I said "I'd never stick an inline fuse holder in the junction box and call it a day!" -- but I don't think doing that strictly meets code.

Comment: Southwire does make a listed single blow fused 14-50 to 5-15 "gas range adapter".

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a false equivalence between neutral and ground.  See your step 5 where you try to attach **hot, hot, neutral** to a NEMA 6, which has no neutral.

Everything after that fails, of course.

You appear to be trying to create ground “out of nothingness” at step 5.  You need to ***obtain*** ground from the proper location.

---

I think the root of your problem is that you are trying to "snatch" electric power from a place you're not allowed to snatch power (stealing from the utility side of the meter??)

The system design of 120/240V AC distribution calls for Hot-Hot-Neutral to come from the utility and through the meter.  The very next stop is the **Service Equipment** which contains a **service disconnect** and typically overcurrent protection (breaker(s)). Sometimes just a main breaker, other times a whole array of them for various feeders and branch circuits.

At that Service Equipment, the **Safety Ground** (properly: Equipment Grounding Conductor) originates.  It is formed at the junction between the **Grounding Electrode System** (ground rods) *AND* the **Neutral-Ground Equipotential Bond** which ties neutral and ground together *at that single point*.  From that point onward, neutral and ground are carried separately.   All this stuff happens for a bunch of reasons.

You want to obtain 120/240V split-phase and you need **Hot, Hot, Neutral, Ground**.  You need to obtain that at an appropriate place *at or past* the Service Equipment, and there must be overcurrent protection (circuit breaker) appropriate to the size of wire which you are coming off with, that defined by NEC Table 310.15(B)(16) or local equivalent.

If you want to set up a second parallel set of Service Equipment also coming off the meter, that is not unprecedented, but there has to be a *really good reason for it*.  Also, your second Service Equipment is obliged to be *right next to* the existing Service Equipment.

What you can't do, for instance, is hotshot straight off the meter over to an outbuilding, with no overcurrent protection *whatsoever* except for a main breaker at the outbuilding.  That was allowed back in the dark ages, but has been written out of NEC decades ago.